# docker build error the folder you are executing pip from can no longer be found

Tags: python-3.x, docker, pip, docker-image, docker-build

I'm making a `Dockerfile` to install `python38` on `centos7` base. Everything works file until `pip3` command. Dockerile looks like this.

```
FROM centos:centos7

RUN RPM_LIST=" \
      gcc \
      make \
      openssl-devel \
      bzip2-devel \
      libffi-devel" && \
    yum install -y $RPM_LIST && \
    curl -O https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.2/Python-3.8.2.tgz && \
    tar xvf Python-3.8.2.tgz && \
    cd Python-3.8.2  && \
    ./configure && \
    make && \
    make install && \
    rm -rf /Python-3.8.2* && \
    yum remove -y $RPM_LIST && \
    pip3 install retrying
```

Error is `The folder you are executing pip from can no longer be found.`.

I changed the last line to `RUN pip3 install retrying` and it started working, but it added an additional `300 MB` to my `image`, which i can't effort.

Any suggestions, what am i missing here or any alternative ways ?

Comment: It seems like the error means what it says: you `cd /Python-3.8.2`, then `rm -rf /Python-3.8.2` while you're still in that directory, so when the `pip3` executes, the current directory is gone.

Comment: Using the standard Docker Hub `python:3.8` image might be easier, unless you _need_ a CentOS base.  Most applications aren't particularly sensitive to the Linux distribution they're running on.

Comment: This is a snippet from a custom `CentOS` image i'm making. The `pip3` call is happening after the installation and the call should be referring to `usr/local/bin/`. This was my thought. Let me snuffle the commands and give it a try.

Comment: I suspect `pip` is installed fine; it's the directory you're currently `cd`'d into that's gone.

Comment: Yeah, shuffling worked and as you said pip s installed fine as well. I kept the removing folder part to the end of the file and it works fine.

Comment: Isn't odd that `pip3` command is not working from `Python-3.8.2` folder? If we add `cd /` to the command list after the `make install` command, `pip3` is also working fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is how the working `Dockerfile` looks like

```
FROM centos:centos7

RUN RPM_LIST=" \
      gcc \
      make \
      openssl-devel \
      bzip2-devel \
      libffi-devel" && \
    yum install -y $RPM_LIST && \
    curl -O https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.2/Python-3.8.2.tgz && \
    tar xvf Python-3.8.2.tgz && \
    cd Python-3.8.2  && \
    ./configure && \
    make && \
    make install && \
    pip3 install retrying && \
    yum remove -y $RPM_LIST && \
    rm -rf /Python-3.8.2*
```

for some reason, calling `pip3` command from `Python-3.8.2` folder was not working. Here i moved the `rm` command after the `pip3` call. Hope this information helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into `The folder you are executing pip from can no longer be found.`

My Dockerfile has not changed in months. It does not install pip.

It *does* force remove and make a folder just prior to running a pip install on a requirements file -- into which pip is supposed to install things.

The fix?  I simply ran it again and it worked. Hmm...

So I am posting this here in case there is some **mysterious timing issue** about which folks wish to collect clues.

--- edit add --

Also, yesterday I ran into this docker issue, which required turning off docker's experimental gRPC feature in its preferences.  Perhaps it could be related somehow?

[Why does Serverless produce an Invalid Cross-device link Error when trying to package or deploy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64048687/why-does-serverless-produce-an-invalid-cross-device-link-error-when-trying-to-pa)