# Why does Serverless produce an Invalid Cross-device link Error when trying to package or deploy?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

When running either command:
`sudo serverless package or sudo serverless deploy`

### I get the following traceback:

> Error: ERROR: Exception: Traceback (most recent call last): File
> “/var/lang/lib/python3.6/shutil.py”, line 550, in move os.rename(src,
> real_dst) OSError: [Errno 18] Invalid cross-device link:
> ‘/tmp/pip-target-wqc5grcw/lib/python/setuptools’ ->
> ‘/var/task/setuptools’
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File
> “/var/lang/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py”,
> line 228, in _main status = self.run(options, args) File
> “/var/lang/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py”,
> line 182, in wrapper return func(self, options, args) File
> “/var/lang/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py”,
> line 456, in run options.target_dir, target_temp_dir, options.upgrade
> File
> “/var/lang/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py”,
> line 514, in _handle_target_dir target_item_dir File
> “/var/lang/lib/python3.6/shutil.py”, line 561, in move symlinks=True)
> File “/var/lang/lib/python3.6/shutil.py”, line 321, in copytree
> os.makedirs(dst) File “/var/lang/lib/python3.6/os.py”, line 220, in
> makedirs mkdir(name, mode) PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission
> denied: ‘/var/task/setuptools’

I’ve created several different projects and they work locally but they never progress beyond this invalid cross-link device Error when trying to deploy or package.

What are my options?

Answer (score 10):

**Edit:** I tried nuking my virtualenv, uninstalling/re-installing `serverless-python-requirements`, deleting/re-pulling the `lambci/lambda` Docker image, no dice.

Then, I stumbled on this [GH issue](https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements/issues/556#issuecomment-728226895). As hinted in it, the experimental Docker feature *Use gRPC FUSE for file sharing* seems to be the cause. I've switched it off in the Docker Preferences for now and deploys are successful.

Comment: Was having an issue with running `pip install` within a docker container. Disabling _se gRPC FUSE_ within Docker preferences fixed the issue for me.

Comment: gRPC fuse was the issue for me too, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I was getting this error when running sls deploy, and disable 'Use gRPC FUSE for file sharing' fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem. See [this issue](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/8498) for a possible solution.

In summary,

1. Remove all cached packages in /Library/Caches/serverless-python-requirements/
2. Remove existing docker image lambci/lambda build-python3.8