# Serverless deploy produces invalid cross-device link

Tags: python, pip, serverless, aws-serverless

#### Problem

I tried installing a new pip package `sendgrid` for my project and although it works locally, it causes my `serverless deploy` call to fail with the following trace:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 791, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
OSError: [Errno 18] Invalid cross-device link: '/tmp/pip-target-i40hnhmr/lib/python/jmespath-1.0.1.dist-info' -> '/var/task/jmespath-1.0.1.dist-info'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 160, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 247, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 566, in run
    self._handle_target_dir(
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 625, in _handle_target_dir
    shutil.move(os.path.join(lib_dir, item), target_item_dir)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 807, in move
    copytree(src, real_dst, copy_function=copy_function,
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 557, in copytree
    return _copytree(entries=entries, src=src, dst=dst, symlinks=symlinks,
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 458, in _copytree
    os.makedirs(dst, exist_ok=dirs_exist_ok)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 223, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/task/jmespath-1.0.1.dist-info'
```

#### What I've tried:

I've already read through the StackOverflow question here([Why does Serverless produce an Invalid Cross-device link Error when trying to package or deploy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64048687/why-does-serverless-produce-an-invalid-cross-device-link-error-when-trying-to-pa)) which is identical to this question, but had no success with its solutions. That is, I've changed file sharing to VirtioFS and osxfs (Legacy) on Docker without any success. I've also deleted the docker images and cached libraries in `~/Library/Caches/serverless-python-requirements/`. Despite doing all these things I still get the same error whenever I run `sudo serverless deploy` or `sudo serverless package`

#### Question

Does anyone know what the cause of the problem is here?

Comment: Have you tried building docker image using aws serverless base image for python?

Comment: Haven't tried that no, not sure exactly how I'd go about it either... Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Okay so I ended up solving this problem but I'm not quite sure how. I think what did it was removing the `sudo` from `sudo serverless deploy`. This initially threw an error because the `.serverless` folder was protected. What I ended up doing was deleting the `.serverless` folder, deleting the caches in my `~/Library/Caches/serverless-python-requirements/ folder, and deleting all the Docker images related to this deployment. Then running `serverless deploy` seemed to work

Comment: The cross-device link message is a red herring: `shutil.move` just first tries `os.rename` and then falls back to copy-and-delete when that fails for that reason.  The permissions error is what really matters.